# Issue with setting integrationServices object while deploying SSIS packages (ispac) using powershell

Tags: powershell, ssis

I am trying to deploy an `.ispac` file using PowerShell and my SSIS instance is running in azure data factory. But it is failing while creating this 
object:

```
$integrationServices = New-Object $SSISNamespace".IntegrationServices" $sqlConnection
```

and I get this error:

> New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Failed toconnect to server ****.database.windows.net."At line:1 char:24 + ...   >nServices = New-Object $SSISNamespace".IntegrationServices" $sqlConne ...            > + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object],  MethodInvocationException
>         + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

I am using [this script from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-deploy-powershell?view=sql-server-2017#for-azure-sql-database-get-the-connection-info).

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: This issue is resolved. I have '$' in the password and added ` before the $ and connection was successful.

Answer (score 0):

connection to sql server was not working due $ in the password. I tried $sql.open() and connection was not established. Now after adding escape sequence before $ sign, it worked